# Why functional objects in C++ for arithmetic operations are implemented as templates?

Tags: c++, operators, arithmetic-expressions

I wonder, why functional objects in **c++** are implemented as templated, with `void` as default type since **c++14**.

For example:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/minus

This object in fact performs arithmetic operation `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, when called by `operator()`.

The `operator()` has to be template to work with different types as arguments, but why does the struct have to be?

EDIT

I can create an operator `std::plus<>`, which may work with a different types in `operator()`:

```
struct Foo{
    int foo;
};

Foo operator+(const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs){
    return {2 * lhs.foo + 3 * rhs.foo};
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& f){
    std::cout << f.foo;
    return os;
 }

int main()
{
    auto op = std::plus<>();
    std::cout << op(5, 3) << "\n";
    std::cout << op(3.14, 2.71) << "\n";
    std::cout << op(Foo(2), Foo(3)) << "\n";
}
```

And this gives the expected output. Or it may be the case, that having specified the type initially you get something more optimized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a design choice. If you specify the type there is no template `operator()`, instead the whole class is a template. The `operator()` is simply something like

```
constexpr T operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const 
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

This is in several ways different from having a template `operator()`.

If we pass a `std::plus<int>` it's a plus functor for specifically `int`s and nothing else.

If we instead passed a `std::plus<>` without specifying the type it would have a templated `operator()`. That functor could apply it's `operator()` to any valid type.

Some advantages with restricting the type from the top of my head:

Since the type is specified the functor can deal with implicit conversion without any issues.

You know for a fact that the functor is not going to silently do things we don't want it to. It's only ever going to do addition on `T`s.

**Edit**

Some examples when the behaviour would differ.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct Foo {};


int main()
{
    auto stringadd = std::plus<std::string>{};
    auto anyadd = std::plus<>{};

    std::cout << stringadd("hey ", "you") << '\n';
    //std::cout << anyadd("hey ", "you") << '\n'; // error: no match for call to '(std::plus<void>) (const char [5], const char [4])'

    //std::cout << stringadd("hey ", 1) << '\n'; // error: no match for call to '(std::plus<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >) (const char [5], int)'
    std::cout << anyadd("hey ", 1) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator I don't really understand the point of the edit. I've addressed the fact that the behaviour is different and some examples of why. It's not about optimization. It's about how the functor interacts with other code.